# Is it a gerund or participle?

Tags: parts-of-speech

> I received a letter, saying something.

Is the word 'saying' a gerund or participle? It bugs me all the day.

Comment: It's a participle, but people these days no longer distinguish gerunds and participles, and simple call them *gerund-participles*. Anyway, have you ever heard about a *dangling modifier*?

Comment: @user178049 dangling modifier? Has it different subject? So, in this sentence, saying modifies the letter, is it? Thank you.

Comment: Opps, I'm sorry. *saying* is not really modifying *letter*, but I consider this as a dangling modifier because it does not clearly modify an object that's should be modified. You **should** rephrase this sentence, it's too ambiguous.

Comment: You mean: It's been bugging you all day. It's nothing because it's not grammatical. Grammatical would be: I received a letter saying nothing about the problem.

Comment: First, ditch the comma; it's useless. "Saying something" is a gerund-participial clause modifying "letter". The head of the clause is the gerund-participle verb "saying". The sentence isn't up to much since it's pretty meaningless. Better to say something like "I received a letter saying something about my having committed a traffic offence".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I received a letter saying something (wrong about you) = I received a letter that was saying something wrong about you.

The "saying" is a present participle, not a gerund, in the sentence.